# Saxon XPathEvaluator only returns the first result

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

I am trying to make some XPaths queries in a XML document using the Saxon 9.5 HE Java Library. I created the query with the net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator, and wanted to get all book titles out of a XML document. Unfortunately I only get the first title. Here is my sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {           
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new File("books.xml").toURI().toURL().toString());
        String x = new XPathEvaluator().evaluate("//book/title", is);

        System.out.println(x);  
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks and kind regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just implemented a solution with the XPathCompiler:

This works fine. If you are interested you can have a look at the source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {           
        Processor proc = new Processor(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
        XPathCompiler xpc = proc.newXPathCompiler();

        XPathSelector selector = xpc.compile("//book/title").load();
        selector.setContextItem(builder.build(new File("books.xml")));
        for (XdmItem item: selector) 
        {
            System.out.println(item.getStringValue());
        }
    }   

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which `XPathEvaluator` is that, the `JAXP` one? I think that implements XPath 1.0 semantics where the string result of evaluating an XPath expression returning a set of nodes returns the string value of the first selected node. You would either need to evaluate to node set or you could use the XPath `"string-join(//book/title, ', ')"`.

If you want to have a sequence of string values you could use http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/sxpath/XPathEvaluator.html although that documentation suggests the preferred way is to use `s9api` with http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XPathCompiler.html.